# Routing ajax requests in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, kohana

In my bootstrap.php I have the following code:

```
// Check if ajax request
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "XMLHttpRequest")
{
    Route::set('ajax', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
}

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

The 'ajax' route is incomplete. What I want to do is if the request is done via. ajax, then Kohana should look for the controller in a subfolder within my controllers called ajax/. So, *if* ajax request then:

http://localhost/myproject/somecontroller/someaction routes to somecontroller inside the ajax subfolder. *If not* ajax then just use the 'default' route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda/callback function/method something like this:

```
Route::set('ajax', function($uri)
    {
        if (Request::$current->is_ajax() AND $params = Route::get('default')->matches($uri))
        {
            $params['directory'] = 'ajax';
            return $params;
        }
    },
    '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))'
);
```

See http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing and http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Route

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Route::set('ajax', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => 'ajax',
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

However, personally, I'd handle both AJAX and non-AJAX requests in the same controller, using `Request::current()->$is_ajax` to tell if it was an AJAX request. The AJAX behavior is probably not significantly different to the non-AJAX, so it might be beneficial to keep both in the same controller. You may end up with code duplication if you handle AJAX requests in a different controller.

Comment: I'm building a website where every page is actually an ajax request, so each ajax controller is for ajax-only calls as it outputs json code.

Comment: This route, if I'm reading it correctly, only routes to the "ajax" directory when the user does not fill out any of the controller, action or id parts right?

Comment: @soren.qvist This route is similar to the default route, except it routes everything to controllers inside the 'ajax' directory (that's what the "directory" setting does). Put it in the if condition in your code block and try it out, it should work. I didn't test it myself.

Comment: You are right, this works! I was having some issues with my .htaccess file.